# Как вывести нужное количество букв?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import math

def getMiddle(s):
    b = str.split(s)
    n = math.ceil(len(b) / 2)
    if len(b) == 1:
        print(b[n - n])
    elif len(b) % 2 == 0:
        print(b[n - 1] + b[n])
    else:
        print(b[n - 1])
```

Выводит полностью слово,которое указывается при вызове функции, как сделать чтобы выводило среднюю букву?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос больше информации: входные данные, результат и что не получилось у вас. Например, вводим: "abc" получаем "b", вводим "abcd" получаем "c"

Comment: Кстати, полезно ещё научиться самостоятельно выявлять ошибки в коде. В вашем случае достаточно было бы вставить `print(b)` сразу после сплита – и становится ясно, что эта строка выполняется не так, как ожидалось. А дальше быстрый поиск описания этого метода и коррекция кода. Легко же `(:`

Answer (score 2):

Функция `str.split` принимает разделитель, который вы не дали. В итоге  `b` равен списку с исходной строкой `b = ['<исходная строка>']`. Решений масса:

**Вариант 1.** `b = list(s)` – простое преобразование строки в список. Каждый символ станет отдельным элементом списка.

**Вариант 2.** `b = s` – объект строки в Питоне поддерживает все те же самые методы индексирования и слайсинга, что и список, поэтому преобразовывать строку к списку не имеет смысла.

---

Комментарий насчёт именования: если называете функцию `getMiddle`, то пусть она возвращает значение, а не выводит его. Иначе это какой-то `showMiddle` получается.

---

Небольшое прояснение по [методу `split`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp). Он принимает строку-сепаратор (который по умолчанию равен знаку пробела – то есть, разделяет слова). Примеры использования:

```
# дефолтное значение разделителя – пробел
>>> str.split('Hello, World!')
['Hello,', 'World!']
# можно обращаться напрямую к объекту
# и передавать строку, а не символ
>>> '1713abc2834bce1895'.split('bc')
['1713a', '2834', 'e1895']
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, нужно вывести букву, стоящую посередине, если число букв нечётное или две буквы, стоящие посередине, если число букв чётное. Тогда можно сделать как-то так:

```
def get_middle(s):
    idx = len(s) // 2
    if len(s) % 2 == 0:
        return s[idx-1:idx+1]
    else:
        return s[idx]

print(get_middle("abra")) # ra
print(get_middle("cadabra")) # a
print(get_middle("alakazam")) # ka
```